# How can I stop wine from modifying my display layout?

Tags: wine

I have two monitors and some wine programs like to disable one of them.

I've tried disabling "Allow the window manager to decorate the windows" and "Allow the window manager to control the windows" however this keeps happening.

Is there a way to stop programs run in wine from modifying your display settings?

Comment: Yeah it is annoying when that happens. In a dual monitor setup, both monitors are claimed by wine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open winecfg

- On the Applications tab, add the desired app to the list via the Add button.
- Once added, select or highlight the added application and change to the Graphic tab.
- Check the box that says "Emulate a virtual desktop" and select the window size.  If you want to run the wine app at full screen on one of your monitors, specify the resolution of the desired screen.

Comment: Thank you! My only small gripe is it gives applications an extra bar at the top. It is perfect otherwise! :)